# How to test my website from my phone on the same local network? 127.0.0.1 doesn't work

Tags: ip-address, localhost

I use a text editor to develop a website (Brackets), I can test on `Chrome` and change screen size on `Chrome`, but I want to test on my actual **iPhone**.

If I try to go to the address : `http://127.0.0.1:49371/index.html` on the mobile, it will not load (only on my mac).
They use the same Wifi.

Comment: Why can't you upload it somewhere and test it on the phone in a staging site?

Comment: @Curnelious Maximillian is correct, `127.0.0.1` is a localhost IP address and will only work on the same computer the web server is running on. Likely you're on a network with NAT and have a private IP address assigned to each device. You'll need to use the private IP address of the computer with the web server running on it instead (e.g., 192.168.0.2). You'll also need to make sure there isn't a firewall blocking port `49371`, which may still work on the same computer but not when connecting from an external device on the network.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Being told there are websites that do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the real local ip address of the computer (not the loopback 127.0.0.1) and make sure it is serving over the lan. More info:

[Stack Overflow - How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** Your PC and you phone are on the *same network* (such as same WiFi).

On Mac you can find your IP address using the `ifconfig` command. Check the `inet` address of your interface such as `en0`. Then you can access that IP address from your phone. For example if you find your IP to be `192.168.1.3`, you can visit the URL http://192.168.1.3:49371/index.html from your phone.

**Case 2** Your PC and you phone are on different networks.

There are a couple of good free services that let you do the same. Ideal for showing something quickly during development/testing:

- https://pinggy.io
- http://localtunnel.me/
- https://ngrok.com/